# Table border at places without cells

Tags: html, css, html-table, border, css-tables

I am trying to create a table in which I want a border all around the table ( and in between rows and columns too ). The problem is that I have some blank spaces in my table where the border of the table does not show, if I try giving an "outline" property to the table, the table border merges with the cells border to create a broader border at some places.

Here is the relevant code -

```
table{
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 1.5em;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #eee;
}
tr,th,td{
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 1.5em;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #fff;
}
```

here is how the table looks -

No Border:

[image]

here is what happens when I add the `outline: 1px solid #ccc;` to the table's property -

Double Border:

[image]

Suggest an efficient solution.

Comment: can you post a fiddle ?

Comment: can you show your html code with css